# antlr4 mixed fragments in tokens

Tags: antlr4

I observe a strange behavior, trying to parse a text using a grammar that contains a statements like the following:

```
fragment A : ('a'|'A') ;
fragment D : ('d'|'D') ;
fragment N : ('n'|'N') ;
KEY_AND : A N D;
```

I created a simple grammar to produce the issue I experience:

```
grammar AndTest;  
mainRule: NAME SEP KEY_AND SEP NAME;
NAME: ('A'..'Z')+ ;
SEP: ';' ;
fragment A : ('a'|'A') ;
fragment D : ('d'|'D') ;
fragment N : ('n'|'N') ;
KEY_AND : A N D;
WS: [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;
```

During grun execution I have got  the following (here we have 'AND' and get an error, but if we have 'And' then we don't):

for **AND**: `echo ANDY ; AND ; ANDY | grun AndTest mainRule -tree`

```
line 1:7 mismatched input 'AND' expecting KEY_AND
(mainRule ANDY ; AND ; ANDY)
```

for **And**: `echo ANDY ; And ; ANDY | grun AndTest mainRule -tree`

```
(mainRule ANDY ; And ; ANDY)
```

**My question**: The error occurred during execution is expected and I missed something in my grammar, or it is a kind of bug in antlr4?

*Environment*: Windows7x32, Java SE 1.8.0_60-b27, antlr 4.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar is matching input "`AND`" to the `NAME` rule before is matches to the `KEY_AND` rule.

The error is expected. `AND` meets the requirements for `NAME` and `NAME` is listed *before* `KEY_AND`. The order of rules is important in antlr.

Moving the `KEY_AND` rule above `NAME` should fix this error.